# Why does Halmos' proof of Zorn's lemma apply to all sets?

Tags: order-theory

Zorn's lemma states that

> If $X$ is a partially ordered set such that every chain in $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ contains a maximal element.

In his proof Halmos firstly replaces the abstract partial ordering by the inclusion order. Then he considers a set of all chains in $X$ (let's call it ${X_C}$) and shows that it has these properties:

- Every subset of each set in ${X_C}$ is in ${X_C}$.
- The union of each chain of sets in ${X_C}$ is in ${X_C}$.

These properties are derived partially from the fact that we are looking at inclusion order.

Later on he proves that every non-empty collection of a non-empty set, satisfying these two properties, has a maximal element, thus proving that the collection ${X_C}$ also has a maximal element. Therefore $X$ has a maximal element.

The problem I see here is that he proved Zorn's lemma only for sets that satisfy the two properties (e.g. sets with inclusion order). If we imagine a partially ordered set whose every chain has an upper bound, which has an ordering that does not lead to such properties, then the proof doesn't include it.

I would like to know what is wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: Certainly this comes down to the step: "Halmos firstly replaces the abstract partial ordering by the inclusion order." He must give some justification for this move, and the answer to your question is to understand this justification. Those of us to don't have a copy of Halmos's book (which book? *Naive Set Theory*?) handy can't possibly answer the question without more information.

Comment: Actually the two properties you mention can be proved for any $X$ without much problem, I don't know why the author would replace $X$ with something ordered by inclusion. But also every ordered set is isomorphic to some ordered set ordered by inclusion so it's not a problem to replace $X$ with such an ordered set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every partial order $(X,\leq)$ is isomorphic to a partial order $(Y,\subseteq)$. Simply define $Y_x=\{y\in X\mid y\leq x\}$, then $Y_x\subseteq Y_{x'}$ if and only if $x\leq x'$.

Now. Add to $Y$ all sets of the form $Y_C=\bigcup_{x\in C}Y_x$ where $C$ is a chain. Since $C$ has an upper bound, any $Y_C$ is a subset of some $Y_x$ (and possibly equal to one).

If $Y$ (with the added $Y_C$'s) has a maximal element, it has to be of the form $Y_x$ for some $x$, since any $Y_C$ must be below (or equal to) some $Y_x$, and we are looking at a maximal element. Therefore $x$ itself was maximal in $X$.